# Can't publish my HaxeFlixel game to html5 due to "Type not found : lime.ui.Joystick" from flash develop

Tags: html, haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, haxeflixel

I get 'C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/3,3,9/openfl/display/Stage.hx:23: characters 7-23 : Type not found : lime.ui.Joystick' Whenever I try to publish to html5 from flash develop. I've run haxelib update on openfl, flixel, and lime, with no change. Has anyone run into this, and is there a simple fix?

Source can be found here: https://github.com/jrdoughty/RTSBase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but you could try to disable gamepads by adding

```
<haxedef name="FLX_NO_GAMEPAD" />
```

in project.xml http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/gamepads/,
or if you need them, you could exclude only for html5 target

```
<haxedef name="FLX_NO_GAMEPAD" if="html5" />
```

Comment: This doesn't stop the compiler warning after adding it with html5 condition or without it sadly

Comment: I've start build with latest haxe, flixel, lime and openfl, and all builds without errors. Try to copy haxe folder with libs and make fresh install

Comment: resinstalling haxe and each library fixed it!

Comment: Background on the error - Joystick API is only available on lime/openfl "legacy", but html5 is always implicitly lime/openfl "next". However, flixel forces "legacy" define by default. Perhaps before the upgrade that define had not yet been removed for flixel's html5 target. Glad to hear it works with latest stuff.